# Initialize a jquery plugin via option after period of time

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Is there an easy way to start a plugin after a certain period of time. I'm thinking of having a start option in my defaults which a user can set to false, and then set to true later. So I guess my question is how would I initialize a plugin with a value and then change that value later.

A few more details. The plugin is my own gallery plugin and I've used it many times in the past, but this time I need to initialize it and have it wait about 10 seconds before it starts to actually slide/fade.

Comment: What's the purpose of this?  Can you explain more about how you would want this to work?  Like when the user clicks on something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Quote OP:** *"So I guess my question is how would I initialize a plugin with a value and then change that value later."*

You would initialize it as normal (within the `document.ready`) and also bind it to an event (like a click) which simply re-invokes the plugin along with the new options when that event happens.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#target').myPlugin({
        // initial options
    });

    $('a.mylink').click(function() {

        $('#target').myPlugin({
            // new options
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: This might work, although I would rather just update one option instead of all of them. Won't this revert to the defaults if I don't specify all of them again?

Comment: @IanHoar, no it will not.  It's being invoked in two different ways.  AFAIK, there is no limitation to the number of times you invoke a plugin on the same page.  But providing an exact solution is proving difficult given the vagueness of your question.

Comment: @IanHoar, you can also have two different sets of options and swap those out as needed using jQuery's `extend` method.

Comment: I will give this a shot. I am using the extend method in my plugin. Ideally I should probably just make a start option, but I was hoping for a quick fix in the short term.

Comment: @IanHoar, again, I don't have the benefit of knowing "the bigger picture" here, but it seems that you have some options.

Comment: Well I know the best option is probably to write that functionality into the plugin, but I was looking for a shortcut. ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can use set timeout function function

```
setTimeout(function() {
//Run function
},2000)//Add value as required
```

Comment: Quote OP:  _"So I guess my question is how would I initialize a plugin with a value and then change that value later."_

Comment: It would help much if you post something about the plugin or code you are going to use.

Comment: I am not the OP... but I agree.  (If you want to direct your comment at somebody in particular, use the `@` sign in front of their username.)

Comment: I know how to use setTimeout, sorry if I was not specific enough. I've updated the question.

Comment: what plugin are you going to use?

Comment: It's a custom plugin I wrote. It's a gallery plugin that does fades and slides and lets me customize a lot of things. But I need it to start cycling after 10 seconds, but everything else still has to initialize.